Why isn't my supplied predicate being matched when using Moq?
Given a simple type I'm testing, say
interface IMyRepo
{
  MyObj GetBy(Expression<Func<MyObj, bool> predicate);
}

so the standard mock setup works just fine:
_repoMock.Setup(x => x.GetBy(y => y.Prop=="A")).Returns(myObjInstance);

It matches on, for example: _repo.GetBy(x => x.Prop=="A")
However, if I have a helper method for my setup:
_repoMock.Setup(Helpers.GenerateGetByMock<IMyRepo, MyObj>(y => y.Prop=="A"));
where
Expression<Func<T, R>> GenerateGetByMock<T, R>(Expression<Func<R,bool>> pred) where T : IMyRepo where R : class
{
  return x => x.GetBy(pred);
}

This will not match in a test on _repo.GetBy(x => x.Prop=="A")!
What is the difference in the generated expressions, and why do I have to use the explicit inline version? Is there any way of using the helper method approach?
Edit: Here's the mock expression with the inline version:

versus with the helper method:


helper method doesn't compile as it is written...

Here's a poorly-written example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/87ajRQ
It'll compile, but not run in .NET Fiddle. It'll run in VS with the Moq required   set in the project.

interface IMyRepo {   MyObj GetBy(Expression<Func<MyObj, bool> predicate); } this is the original interface from the question, not R GetBy<R> as in the fiddle.

Yes, my bad. Always good to write the working minimal example before asking the question I guess :)
The two 'Setup' properties look identical in both cases, but only the first one is matched properly.
As both you and Mark have implied though, this is really bending Moq out of shape and probably needs a better approach!

your fiddle modified - still runs if things are made public - added the extension method from my answer and it works.

it's not Moq's issue really.

Nope, it's definitely as a result of poor choices I have made!

The issue is with how the compiler generates the Expression<Func<T, R>> from your helper method:
Expression<Func<T, R>> GenerateGetByMock<T, R>(Expression<Func<R,bool>> pred) where T : IMyRepo where R : class
{
  return x => x.GetBy(pred);
}

which doesn't compile, so presumably you actually mean this:
Expression<Func<T, MyObj>> GenerateGetByMock<T>(Expression<Func<MyObj, bool>> pred)
where T : IMyRepo {
    return x => x.GetBy(pred);
}

given that you have those types in your example:
public interface IMyRepo {
    MyObj GetBy(Expression<Func<MyObj, bool>> predicate);
}

public class MyObj {
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}

the compiler for some reason isn't smart enough to do this:
public Expression<Func<I, MyObj>> GenerateGetByMockManually<I>(
Expression<Func<MyObj, bool>> predicate)
where I : IMyRepo {
    // x
    var outerParameter =
       Expression.Parameter(typeof(I), "x");
    // x.GetBy
    var getByMethod = typeof(I).GetMethod("GetBy");
    //x.GetBy(predicate)
    var expressionCall = Expression.Call
        (outerParameter, getByMethod,
        [Expression.Quote(predicate)]); 
        // here the compiler just defaults to capturing the argument in a temp class field 
       // and expose it via constant

    //x => x.GetBy(predicate)
    var manualBuilt = Expression.Lambda<Func<I, MyObj>>
        (expressionCall, [outerParameter]);

    return manualBuilt;
    
    // Debugging
    var expressionVisitor = new GetByPredicateVisitor(predicate);
    var newExpression = expressionVisitor.Visit(manualBuilt);

    return (Expression<Func<I, MyObj>>)newExpression;
}

If you use the above method, things will work out as expected.
If you still want to rely on the compiler for most of the work, you'd need to make use of an ExpressionVisitor implementation to modify the argument constant part and probably the most flexible way would be to create an extension method for this predicate quoting:
public static class ExpressionQuoterExtensions {

    public static Expression<Func<I, M>> QuotePredicate<I, M>(
    this Expression<Func<I, M>> expression, Expression<Func<M, bool>> predicate) {
        var expressionVisitor = new PredicateVisitor<M>(predicate);
        return (Expression<Func<I, M>>)expressionVisitor.Visit(expression);
    }

    public class PredicateVisitor<M> : ExpressionVisitor {
        Expression<Func<M, bool>> _predicate;

        public PredicateVisitor(Expression<Func<M, bool>> predicate) {
            _predicate = predicate;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) {
            var newArguments = node.Arguments
                .Select(argumentNode => {
                    // if predicate
                    if (argumentNode.Type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(Expression))
                       && argumentNode.Type.IsGenericType
                       && argumentNode.Type.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 1
                       && argumentNode.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(Func<M, bool>)
                       ) {
                        argumentNode.ToString().Dump(); //debugging
                        // can be __DisplayClass5_0`2[IMyRepo,MyObj]).predicate...
                        return Expression.Quote(_predicate);
                    }
                    return argumentNode;
                })
                .ToList();

            return Expression.Call(node.Object, node.Method, newArguments);
        }
    }
}

Then you'd need to modify your method a little:
public Expression<Func<I, M>> GenerateGetByMockWithQuoter<I, M>(
    Expression<Func<M, bool>> predicate)
 where I : IMyRepo
 where M : class {
    Expression<Func<I, M>> expression = x => x.GetBy<M>(predicate);
    return expression.QuotePredicate(predicate);
}

OP's fiddle - modified to use the extension method - working.
Some manual testing code:
var _repoMock = new Mock<IMyRepo>();

var manualExpression = GenerateGetByMockManually<IMyRepo>(y => y.Prop == "A");
_repoMock
//.Setup(x => x.GetBy(y => y.Prop == "A"))
.Setup(manualExpression)
.Returns(new MyObj() {
    Prop = "foo"
});
Console.WriteLine(_repoMock.Object.GetBy(x => x.Prop == "A").Prop); // foo

var compilerAssistedExpression = GenerateGetByMockWithQuoter<IMyRepo,MyObj>(y => y.Prop == "B");
_repoMock
.Setup(compilerAssistedExpression)
.Returns(new MyObj() {
    Prop = "bar"
});
Console.WriteLine(_repoMock.Object.GetBy(x => x.Prop == "B").Prop); // bar


Kudos. I will never cease to be amazed that there are technical enough people in the world who are willing to put in enough effort to even get other people's bad ideas going, just for the sake of 'because it can be done'. :)
My key takeaway: I know pathetically little about Expressions, lexical analysis and compiler design...

@oflahero expression trees are definitely interesting, this answer got me maybe the best resource for laying the groundwork

Async version!
https://dotnetfiddle.net/3F0ZAi

As the screen shots show, they're two different expressions. Each Expression<T> object is a small expression tree that Moq may compare to figure out if it matches another expression tree.
I haven't looked at the Moq code based for a long time, but IIRC it doesn't evaluate the expressions. It compares them to see if they're sufficiently similar. Like in basic compiler theory, one can implement various compiler optimizations to simplify or generalize the expression trees, but I don't think Moq 'follows' and inlines method calls.
After all, in order to inline a method call, a compiler or interpreter needs to know whether or not it's safe to do so. That's not always the case. One simple case where it's not safe to inline a method is when the method has local variables with names equal to variables in the wider context. Thus, in such a case, inlining at least requires variable renaming.
Frankly, I'd be surprised if Moq implements expression tree optimization to that level of sophistication (even if, in compiler theory, this is really at the undergraduate level, so not even that sophisticated). That's not to imply that Moq isn't a sophisticated library, but rather to say that it's fundamentally not a compiler; it has a different purpose.

As a general observation, once you get into too gnarly territory with a dynamic mock library (be it Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy, etc. - it doesn't really matter), take that as feedback that you're painting yourself into a maintenance-nightmare corner. Consider a different design or test strategy.
I'd strongly suggest that you consider state-based testing instead of interaction-based testing, but as a smaller, isolated trick, you can sometimes use the Resemblance idiom to work around certain problems related to Moq. I'm not sure, however, that Resemblance will address this particular problem; I haven't analyzed it in detail, and I'm not sure I have enough information to do so anyway.

Thanks Mark. This is the most sensible reaction, I think. Although I reckon it's overall the more 'correct' response, you'll surely understand if I give Ivan the 'answer' for the sheer amount of bloodyminded technical effort that went into getting my bad idea up and running!
